# How to show admob interstitial ad when listview item is clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I have a fragment that contains a listview , I want to show interstial ad whene the user click a listview item , I tried the following code but it is not showing :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

......

mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mContext);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }

            }
        });

......        

return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up new class which have set, load and show interstatialAd static methods as below:

```
public class AdSetup {
    // Application context returned by function --> Application.get()

    public static String TesttingDeviceID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    final static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Application.get());  

    public static void setInterstitial() {
        try {
            if (mInterstitialAd.getAdUnitId() == null) {
                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(Application.get().getString(R.string.interstitialAd));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void loadInterstatial() {
        try {
            setInterstitial();

            AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    Log.e("mInterstetial onloaded", "onloaded isLoaded" + mInterstitialAd.isLoaded());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                    Log.e("mInterstetial onloaded", "onloaded onAdFailedToLoad");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
//                    super.onAdOpened();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
//                    super.onAdClosed();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClicked() {
//                    super.onAdClicked();
                }

            });
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void showInterstatial() {
        try {
            Log.e("mInterstetial show ", "isLoaded" + mInterstitialAd.isLoaded());
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() && mInterstitialAd.getAdUnitId() != null) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {

                loadInterstatial();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

How to call this methods on click of the list item or the onCreate() of the new Activity to comply with the interstatial ad policy:

```
  AdSetup.showInterstatial();  // Show ad if already loaded else load Ad
  AdSetup.loadInterstatial(); // Load new ad
```

**Make sure to follow the policies listed in the below links:**

[Disallowed interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en)

> App load or exit Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when
>   exiting apps as interstitials should only be placed in between pages
>   of app content. Ads should not be placed in applications that are
>   running in the background of the device or outside of the app
>   environment. It should be clear to the user which application the ad
>   is associated with or implemented on.

[Recommended interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201350?hl=en)

Also, add Application class:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    //    public static DeviceName.DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
    private static Application _instance;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
            _instance = this;

    }

//return the App context
    public static Application get() {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Also declare the `Application` class in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as you can see below first line:

```
 <application
            android:name=".Application"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: thx ,I tried ur solution it shows me error Cannot resolve method 'get()' .

Comment: I have updated the answer with `Appliaction` class and the declaration of the same in `manifest`. `Application.get()` defined in above class method return the `Application` context. As it called at start of application. Make sure to add interstatialAd test id for debugging as you might not able see the live ads on the debug app.

Comment: ok I did all of that but still not showing , I think the problem here is not how the ads are declared but where to put load and show method in a fragment cuz its working fine on other activities, also whene I checked the log I found this error : Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.

Comment: There is possibility that the Ad may not already loaded each time you try to show. What is the `error code` when the ad Fails to load?  You can put below methods in onCreateView() or in onResume() method of Fragment  --> 
 `AdSetup.showInterstatial(); AdSetup.loadInterstatial();` onCreateView() method  will be called once only while fragment is created.

Comment: are Your Fragments inside a view pager?

Comment: the ads are shown fine in the oncreate method of the fragment but when I place them in setOnItemClickListener() methode nothing is shown

Comment: As code have the error log printed in method `AdLoaded` and `onAdFailedToLoad`. See in the Logcat with search "mInterstetial". See if the code is being called and "ad is loaded" or "failed to load" in such cases. You can also call `loadInterstatial()` inside `onAdClosed` method in case if you are loading Ads frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this in my code. It works. In the example that you gave I did not see if you implemented AdListener after AdRequest.Builder. If not, here is an example of that:

```
ExampleInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            ExampleInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        }

    });
```

Next, it appeared in your example that you just have the interstitial ad to show onItemClick but do you have an intent to move to a new activity also set there? I didn't see it. Check out my code below. I set the intent to start the new activity then I show the add after. Just a thought because this works for me. Good luck!

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


                if (ExampleInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    ExampleInterstitial.show();
                }

                else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }

    });
```